# Show that, for $x$ close enough to $a$, $||f(x)|| \leqslant e^{k||x-a||} \;\;\,||f(a)||.$

Tags: solution-verification, normed-spaces

**Exercice :** Let $E$ be a Banach space, $U$ an open of $E$, and $f$ a differentiable application from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that, for all $x\in U$, $||df(x)|| \leqslant k||f(x)||$.
Show that for $x$ close enough to $a$, $||f(x)|| \leqslant e^{k||x-a||} \;\;\,||f(a)||$.

**My attempt :**
Let \begin{align*}g : [0,1&] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ &t \longmapsto g(t)=f(a+t(x-a))\end{align*}
By MVT, $||g(1)-g(0)|| \leqslant  \underset{t\in[0,1]}{\sup} ||dg(t)||  \leqslant \underset{t\in[0,1]}{\sup} ||df(a+t(x-a)|| \,||x-a|| \leqslant k||x- a|| \,||f(x)||$, or $g(1)=f(x)$ and $g(0)=f(a),$ we get $$||f(x)-f(a)||\leqslant k||x-a|| \,||f(x)||.$$
Or $||f(x)|| \leqslant ||f(x)-f(a)||+||f(a)||, $ thus $||f(x)|| \leqslant k||x-a||\,||f(x)||+||f(a)||.$
$||f||$ is continuous so for $x$ close enough to $a$, we have $||f(x) \sim ||f(a)|| $, and and $k||x-a||+1\sim e^{k||x-a||} \;\;$, then for $x$ close enough to $a$, $$||f(x)|| \leqslant e^{k||x-a||} \;\;\,||f(a)||.$$

---

I think I should use an $\varepsilon-\delta$ approch . Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your map $f$ takes real values, right? So why do you use the vector norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ notation and not the absolute value $\vert \cdot \vert$?

Comment: [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) should be useful.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I prefer to use the notation of a norm more than the absolute value. Should I not to use it  ?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thanks a lot, it's so useful.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you please elaborate? why do you think it's odd ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First
suppose $f(a) >0$, let $\eta(x) = \log f(x)$. Then we have
$\|D \eta (x) \| \le k$ for $x$ close to $a$ (so that $f(x) > 0$) and
so $|\eta(x)-\eta(a)| = |\log {f(x) \over f(a)}|\le k \|x-a\|$ from which we get
$\log {f(x) \over f(a)}\le k \|x-a\|$ and so
$f(x) \le f(a) e^{k \|x-a\|}$.

If $f(a) \neq 0$, we see that same condition applies to $t f$, where $t$ is chosen so that $tf(a)=|f(a)|$.

Finally, if $f(a) = 0$, then choose $\delta>0$ such that for $x \in C=\overline{B}(a,\delta)$ we have
$\|Df(x)\| \le {1 \over 2}$ and $k \delta < 1$. Then using the mean value theorem we have $|f(x)-f(a)| \le {1 \over 2} \|x-a\|$ for $x \in C$.

Now suppose $|f(x)-f(a)| \le {1 \over 2} k^n \|x-a\|^{n+1}$ for $x \in C$.
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
|f(x)-f(a)| &\le& \|Df(\zeta)\|\|x -a\| \\
&\le& k |f(\zeta)-f(a)| \|\|x-a\| \\
&\le& {1 \over 2} k^{n+1} \|\zeta-a\|^{n+1} \|x-a\| \\
&=& {1 \over 2} k^{n+1} \|x-a\|^{n+2}
\end{eqnarray}
In particular, letting $ n \to \infty$ we see that $f(x) = f(a)$ and hence the
result holds close to $a$.

Comment: Differentiate $\eta$.

Comment: Please ignore my (now deleted) comment about being odd.

Comment: Thank you so much @copper.hat

Comment: I think there should be a single proof (along the lines of the $f(a)=0$ case above) that should work, just don't have time/energy at the moment.

Comment: It's okey Sir, thank you for your time/energy. I have only one more question : What's wrong in my attempt? because I don't think that if $a \leq b$ and $b \sim c$ $\implies $ $a \leq c$. Isn't it?

Comment: @H_K It needs to be more rigorous to be a proof, starting with where you use $\sim$.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much Sir @copper.hat